# Ninject fails to bind when running from NUnit

Tags: c#, nunit, ninject

i have come across a problem i am not sure how to best solve, ideally without redoing the code.

Prologue:
I was handed an existing application to maintain and as necessary, upgrade. It's an C# application. Now, i am not a pro when it comes to c#, but i am good enough to get things done while not making anyones eyes bleed when reading my code.
The problem is, the application uses NUnit (not that big of a problem, i have experience with that and i understand the basics) and Ninject (thats a different story).

Issue:
The application uses Ninject to bind several classes to the kernel. My goal was to modify the application a bit to allow support for some different objects.

Now, when i debug the application or i build it and deploy, it works. 
However, running Nunit, i get an *Ninject.ActivationException: Error activating IDatabaseConnection* exception. (IdatabaseCnnection is an interface from internal library.

I tried to recreate the test that fails in an console application and it works there as well, it fails only when run through NUnit

```
Ninject.ActivationException: Error activating IDatabaseConnection
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
Activation path:
  3) Injection of dependency IDatabaseConnection into parameter databaseConnection of constructor of type OrderMailDefinitionSource
  2) Injection of dependency IMailDefinitionSource into parameter mailDefinitionSource of constructor of type DocumentMailService
  1) Request for DocumentMailService

Suggestions:
  1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for IDatabaseConnection.
  2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into the kernel.
  3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.
  4) If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the constructors parameter name.
  5) If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct.
```

So as far as i can tell, for some reason when running through NUnit, the binding fails. Running it in any way just not through NUnit, it works.

If you would have any ideas, i would be thankfull.
Have a nice day.

**Answer**
This was the problem (originally didnt use the CodeBase property). Nunit didnt copy the DLLs and so failed to load about 21 different dlls. After this was fixxed it worked.

```
 kernel.Bind(x => x.FromAssembliesInPath(Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath))
                           .SelectAllClasses()
                           .BindDefaultInterface());
```

Comment: If your bindings are declared in your composition root of your actual app, but you're then running nunit tests in a different project, the composition root changes. You either have to bind them again in your test comp root or mock or new up those specific objects.

Comment: thanks, i will look into it, any chance you could direct me with an url to some valid source?

Comment: also, check out the mocking extension for Ninject: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.mockingkernel/wiki

Comment: +1 to @YannickMeeus, as chances are your UT is not running your application instantiation code. It is a unit test after all, so this is expected. A possible solution to save you writing bindings all the time would be to modularise the bindings out, separating concerns, then load specific ones in your tests using `_kernel.Load(INinjectModule)`. You can then override with mocks as you see fit for each test.